# Sorting in Solr with limited records

Tags: solr, solr4

Schema:

```
<field name="id" type="string" required="true" 
       indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" 
       required="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true"/>
```

Lets say my database has four different values for type, example type1, type2, type3 and type4. And my database has n number of records.

Now I want solr query to get results (20 records) which includes 5 records of type1, 5 records of type2, 5 records of type3, 5 records of type4. in a sorting order of type1 to type4.

Answer (score 1):

[Result grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) is what you're looking for:

```
group=true&group.field=type
```

`sort` will work by sorting the groups instead, while `group.sort` sorts the documents inside each group. You can also use `group.main` to make the result of grouping the main response from the query.